# Unable to locate filter on Gas Furnace

Tags: furnace, gas, filter

[image]

Can not find where the filter for this furnace is. It is a gas Rheem Criterion II. Have watched YouTube videos but none look like mine. Thermostat keeps saying filter needs replacement.

Comment: The thermostat is saying "needs replacement" based purely on "number of hours of furnace 'On' since last marked as replaced". So it doesn't mean much. That being said, if you don't know where the filter is then it is quite likely that it **does** need either replacement (if disposable) or cleaning. Typically filter is in the bottom where the circulated air comes in to the furnace, but it does vary.

Comment: The filter doesn’t have to be at the furnace.  One of my rental units is a small place with a single return intake.  The filter fits behind the grate for the return. Specifically [this](https://www.lowes.com/pd/White-Steel-Louvered-Sidewall/Ceiling-Grilles-(Rough-Opening:-20-in-x-20-in%3B-Actual:-22.57-in-x-22.57-in)/1000034169).

Comment: Bad link above, use this one:  https://www.amazon.com/dp/B0064QHV88/ref=cm_sw_r_sms_c_api_i_UqdMCb4V70R0M

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved? If so, please give a check-mark to the answer or write up your own answer explaining what you did to get it fixed and give yourself a check mark. That will help others with this kind of problem know that this has a resolution and is a good place to look for their answer.

Comment: Voting to close. Questions remain and OP hasn't been back.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a down-flow or up-flow. Do you have vents/registers in each room on the floor or high on the wall/ceiling? If they are on the floor, you have a down-flow, and need to locate the intake side in your ceiling. In some homes, this is located near the thermostat. You will have a grate in the ceiling, behind that is most likely where the filter is/should be. If it is up-flow, you should have a filter in the lower part of the furnace itself. This looks like a down-flow, therefore you should have a grate or intake vent in the ceiling somewhere. It is possible that the previous owner took it out and never replaced it.

Comment: The *unit* is upside down, so it's down-flow. So there's probably a large ceiling grate somewhere with a filter behind it, if you trace the ducts going up.

Comment: Flow direction has nothing to do with vent location and everything to do with cabinet orientation. Vent location is largely a regional thing as much as anything, reflecting the primary HVAC need--heat or cooling, as well as home construction type.